# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'e' in java webapp

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a java webapp running in tomcat 7.0.48 and it runs normally in my pc (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), but on the server (Debian Squeeze) it gives this exception when I execute an action:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'e'
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:826)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:634)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:605)
        at com.opensymphony.webwork.components.Date.end(Date.java:307)
        at com.opensymphony.webwork.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:21)
       ...
```

Comment: What did you expect character `e` to do in the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern?

Comment: I don't know, I do not made this code, I have to maintain it and there is no documentation, but I search for the use of SimpleDateForm and i don't find any use with character 'e'.

Comment: The stacktrace shows that it fail during processing of a JSP tag, likely called `<date>`, so you need to look at your JSP for that bad format string.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the pattern of SimpleDateFormat. If it's format is like ("eee, dd. MMM yyyy") then change it to ("EEEE, dd. MMM yyyy").

Since you have not posted your code, below is an example that produces the error.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

   String date = new SimpleDateFormat("eee, dd. MMM yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-07-21"));

}
```

If you will run the above program then you will get the following error.
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'e'**

To resolve the issue, you will have to modify the pattern by capitalizing the letter e.

```
   String date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd. MMM yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-07-21"));
```

Also, have a  look at the docs here, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html then in the **Date and Time Patterns** section, it says:

***Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings. Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote. All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting or matched against the input string during parsing.***

As said in the documentation, unquoted letters will be treated as pattern letters. If you don't want it to be be treated as pattern then just surround the letter e using quotes ('e').

Below is a demonstration. Let's say i want to print the current date followed by letter e followed by the current time then i can do the following.

```
  SimpleDateFormat f =
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd 'e' hh.mm.ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

Running the above program gives the following output.

```
2017.07.21 e 12.38.39
```

If you will unquote the letter e, then you will get **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'e'**.

**Update:** The letter E is used to represent day time in week. If you also want to print the day time, then use it like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat f =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd EEEE hh.mm.ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(f.format(new Date()));
```

O/P: `2017.07.21 Friday 12.53.58 NPT`

If you replace EEEE by E then the output will be

O/P: `2017.07.21 Fri 12.53.58 NPT`